# Legend goes behind the lines in R plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I am generating a plot using the following sample code

```
x=seq(1,10, length=100)       
y=seq(-5,5,length=100)    
pdf("plot.pdf")   
plot(y~x, type="n", xlab="", ylab="")     
for(i in 1:4){   
y=rnorm(100, mean=i, sd=i)   
lines(x,y, type="l",lty=i)     
}   
legend("topright", legend=c("a", "b", "c"), lty=c(1,2,3,4), pch=c(1,2,3,4))   
dev.off()
```

and when I save  the plot in pdf, then the legend goes behind the drawn lines. While I want that the graphs should looks like the following while saving in the form of pdf.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're seeing, the background color for the legend defaults to `"transparent"`. To set it instead to an opaque `"white"`, use its `bg` parameter, like this:

```
legend("topright", legend=c("a", "b", "c"), lty=c(1,2,3,4), pch=c(1,2,3,4),
       bg = "white")
```

[image]

Comment: @user3275911 You bet. To indicate to other users that this answers your question, you can click the "accept" checkmark just to the left of the answer. (That also of course applies to the other questions you've asked -- **if** they've been satisfactorily answered, it's customary to indicate that with a "check").

Answer (score 0):

It's not on top, it's transparent. set the argument `bg = 'white'` in the legend command.